# How do I correctly call the endpoint below?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, urlencode, urldecode

When searchItem parameter has special characters like "+", the special character is omitted out upon hitting the endpoint.
I tried URL encoding the parameter but that causes a 404 error too.
Please help

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("search/{searchItem}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Search(string searchItem)
    {

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The very first idea is to create binding model and get the value from body.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("search")]
public HttpResponseMessage Search([FromBody] SearchItemDto model)
{

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```